# ajax aspx script arguments polish (special) characters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, character-encoding

I'm using ajax to invoke aspx server side script to send email message. Here is my ajax send function:

```
//global variables-------------------------------------------------------
var html_dir = "/Html/"
var net_dir = "/Net/"
//ajax request-----------------------------------------------------------
function ajaxRequest(url, cfunc, asynch)
{
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    response = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// code for IE6, IE5
else
{
    response = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

    //send request
    response.onreadystatechange = cfunc;
    response.open("GET", url, asynch);
    response.send();
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this how I run this function:

```
ajaxRequest(net_dir + "SendForm.aspx?emailBody=" + emailBody, formSent, true);
```

it works fine but I have problem with polish characters (łńóąę etc). In email and also in SendForm.aspx script (when debuging) there are some strange characters instead of polish letters. How can I fix it?

Comment: Which charset are you using for the output of your server response? It should be some Unicode character set, as JS uses UCS-2.

Comment: Can You explain where check it? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to build and run my page.

Comment: I don't know anything about ASP development. But if don't even know which charset you are sending nor know how to check that in your environment, I assume, that this is the error.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the `emailBody` parameter:

```
ajaxRequest(net_dir + "SendForm.aspx?emailBody=" + encodeURIComponent(emailBody), formSent, true);
```

It will then be

```
encodeURIComponent("łńóąę") === "%C5%82%C5%84%C3%B3%C4%85%C4%99"
```

Which is safe to use in an url.

On the server side, if it's not automatically done, you need to decode it then:

```
string emailBody = HttpUtility.UrlDecode( Request.QueryString["emailBody"], 
                             Encoding.UTF8 );
                          //Javascript's encodeURIComponent is always UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same problem before some time. You can replace your special characters to some seperations lie '-' or ','. When you will get the response update your string with your special characters and send the mail.

It may help you.